# Sinatra encoding query string

Tags: sinatra

I've made a very simple sinatra application which displays a frameset with 3 frames. When I set the 'src' parameter for the the frames however, sinatra re-encodes the query string I chose.

For example I enter:

```
"url.com/page?var1=val1&var2=val2"
```

What I end up seeing however is something like:

```
"url.com/page?var1=val1&amp;var2=val2"
```

All my &'s were turned into &-a-m-p-;'s. Is there anyway to disable this? Why does this happen?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm guessing this is a feature of the template language you're using. What do you use for templates?

Comment: I'm using haml and yeah it was because I was escaping the html. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably happening because you have an "escape all html" flag turned on somewhere. Your template language should support flagging strings as "safe"--check out http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#auto_escape_html for more details.